# How to insert unique value in mongodb with c

Tags: c, mongodb

I want to insert a unique 'host' value into a mongo collection. Here is my code:

```
void
mongo_dns_unresolved_push(char *host)
{
        bson_error_t error;
        bson_t *update = NULL;
        bson_t *query = NULL;
        query = BCON_NEW("host", BCON_UTF8(host));
        update = BCON_NEW("$set", "{", "host", BCON_UTF8(host), "}"
                          "$setOnInsert", "{", "host", BCON_UTF8(host), "}", "upsert:true" );
        if (!mongoc_collection_update_one(unresolved_collection, query, update, NULL, NULL, &error)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error.message);
        }
}
```

My code aborts with the following error:

```
/build/mongo-c-driver-RRvvb_/mongo-c-driver-1.16.1/src/libbson/src/bson/bcon.c:785 bcon_append_ctx_va(): precondition failed: type == BCON_TYPE_UTF8
```

How should I modify the above code to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

```
void
mongo_dns_unresolved_push(char *host)
{
        bson_t *doc;
        bson_error_t error;
        bson_t *update = NULL;
        bson_t *query = NULL;
        doc = bson_new();
        BSON_APPEND_BOOL(doc, "upsert", "true");
        query = BCON_NEW("host", BCON_UTF8(host));
        update = BCON_NEW("$set", "{", "host", BCON_UTF8(host), "}");
        if (!mongoc_collection_update_one(unresolved_collection, query, update, doc, NULL, &error)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error.message);
        }
        bson_destroy(doc);
}
```